# Sharing game between devices?

Tags: clicker-heroes

Is it possible to play the same game on multiple devices?

For example, I've got my main game on Steam, but with the release of this on iOS, I'd like to be able to play on my iPod without starting over.

My gut feeling says no, but figured I'd ask.

Comment: You can do it. Save it as text and load it elsewhere.

Comment: That feels more like a "copy my game and play it in two places"; ideally I'd be looking to have the same game on both devices.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I feel like using the Google Play sign in did once sync my tablet and phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currenty the mobile versions on Android and iOS do not have a setting to save the game, nor to import a save game. If they did you would have to copy the text of the game save between switching devices. This seems impractical for what you want. If you were using this on a desktop and then using a mobile device you could use a [remote desktop setup](http://www.howtogeek.com/180953/3-free-ways-to-remotely-connect-to-your-macs-desktop/) like chrome remote desktop or vnc.

But no, if you have the iOS or Android version, right now it doesn't run the same game on two devices at once.

Though, given that the steam client has a mobile version, it would be awesome if one day Steam Cloud support extended to mobile games.

Answer (score -1):

And now after playing the mobile version for a bit; I'm not sure that it's even viable.

As far as i can see; there's no screen to import a save game into; and the ruby scale differs wildly from the PC version.

Comment: Yes I missed that I could neither import nor save the text representation of a save game on Android. I wondered if you could on iOS but it also seems not so.

Answer (score -1):

As of now, you can only export save texts from one mobile device to another. I have tried to import a save code from my computer to my ipad, but it failed.